# UITextView: Replace Special Characters

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uitextview

How can I replace special characters in my UITextView?

I'm receiving an NSString that contains characters such as `"I&#39;m"` instead of `I'm` and I'd like to reformat so it appears properly in my app.

Comment: Do those HTML entities appear if you don't remove the HTML tags or only after removing the tags?

Comment: good point – actually, this is an issue regardless of removing the HTML tags (I've edited the question to reflect this)

Comment: got it, thanks for sharing the link to the original question.  I ended up incorporating the library mentioned, and it worked.